# How to enable qtwebkit webcore logs ?

Tags: qt, qt5, qtwebkit, qtcore, qtwebengine

Im relatively a noob to QT .

I wanted to understand how a browser talks to qtwebkit and how do i enable the logs for all the in the html level of webcore inside qt.

Also Where does QTwebkit generally write the log files.

im using QT 5

anyhelp would be appreciated , Thank You

Answer (score 0):

QtWebKit can print various logs to stderr, but only in debug builds (it is possible to have them in release builds as well by defining -DLOG_DISABLED=0, but it is not supported and may require some source modifications).

To enable logs, specify list of desired log channels in environment variable `QT_WEBKIT_LOG`

- Any non-empty value of `QT_WEBKIT_LOG` enables `NotYetImplemented` channel, that is probably not interesting for you (unless you are developing WebKit)
- Value `all` (available only in QtWebKit technology preview, see below) enables all channels
- You can find possible channel names in Source/WebCore/platform/Logging.h